# Javascript get text inside a <span> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I need to get the text that is inside a  element.

I can only grab the class of this element and NOT the ID.

```
<span class="fileName">test.png</span>
```

So I need a way to get `test.png`, but as you see I have only the class of the  element and not the ID.

Just notice also that we may have more `<span class="fileName"></span>`, so it could look like this

```
<span class="fileName">test1.png</span>
<span class="fileName">test2.png</span>
<span class="fileName">test3.png</span>
<span class="fileName">test4.png</span>
```

In the case we have more, like the example above, I need to get ALL the values and not only one, because I need to pass this value to another page with jQuery. So it should be able to get one value or more from that  element.

Please help!

And also I am not a javascript expert!

Comment: Please no tags, "hellos" or "thanks". SO is not forum.

Comment: use counter, e.g $(".fileName").eq(counter) or .get(counter) or you can use .each(function(event){});

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var filenames = $('.fileName').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

The array `filenames` will contain all the names of the images. You can pass on this array to another jQuery function, or anywhere else you like to do so.

[You can test it here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mrJuD/)

#### Update

Since you request the filenames to be a string separated by a comma, you can do it like this:

```
var filenames = $('.fileName').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');
```

Now, `filenames` will contain the string `test1.png,test2.png,test3.png,test4.png`.

Comment: It returns an array..How do I get the plain values and not the Array. Is there a way to get the values of this array?

Comment: `filenames.toString()`, will do just fine if you want the seperator to be a comma `,`. Otherwise, you can use `filenames.join('yourSeparatorHere')`. Once you have the array, you can do anything you like with it. :)

Comment: Can you include it in the code above? As I said I am not a javascript expert. It does not have any sense for me. I just want to get in the var filenames the name of each file separated by comma, nothing more =(

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName`: http://jsfiddle.net/pCswS/.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("fileName");
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elems[i].innerHTML);
}
alert(arr);
```

(Since you didn't tag the question with jQuery I assume you have to do it with plain JavaScript.)

Comment: Same as above, it returns the word: Array. But how do I get the real names?

Comment: @DiegoP: It does work for me - otherwise change it into `alert(arr.join())`, which converts it into a string (with commas between the elements).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span.fileName').each(function() {
    var fileName = $(this).text();
    doSomethingWithFileName(fileName);
});
```

Here the `span.fileName` selector returns all spans with class fileName then we iterate through, reading the text from each one. You may want to find a container element first and then only iterate inside that, e.g.

```
var $container = $('#myFileNames');
$container.find('span.fileName').each( ... );
```

Comment: @AndyL always the way - sorry. Actually I misread that he wants all the values in an array: Shef's answer is better.

Comment: ok but how do I get the real names. Now I just get the word : Array

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/VDVL9/) my take:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('fileName');
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    values.push(spans[i].innerHTML);
}

// Example of processing: alert the values
alert(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery selector

```
$("span.fileName").html()
```

Comment: it just returns one value and not All