# Javascript: get plain text inside a span which has other nested tags present

Tags: javascript, dom, html

Just for you guys to note, of course I have read this first:
[Javascript get text inside a <span> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650755/javascript-get-text-inside-a-span-element?rq=1)

However, my case is not that easy, let alone because I need to do it natively, without `jQuery`.

Supposing we have this on an arbitrary web page:

```
<span id="entry1" class="entries">
<a href="http://whereyourpicis.at/pic.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 1em;"><img src="http://whereyourpicis.at/pic.jpg" border="0"></a>
++ This is the plain text we want to get from the SPAN block. ++
<span id="nested2"><a onclick="doSomething()">Action!</a></span>
</span>
```

I've tried anything imaginable, but I can't say any of the "solutions" I tried was a good one, since it feels like a total kludge taking the *whole* innerHTML and then doing some `sed`-style regex magic on it.

There must be a more elegant way to accomplish this, which is why I'm asking here.

BTW I've also found out that even `nextSibling()` cannot work here.

Comment: What's wrong with `my_span.textContent`?

Comment: Oh, you need to target just that one line. Hard to tell from your unindented HTML. There are several approaches, but ultimately why is that text not wrapped in an element? Can't you change the markup? I could give a solution for this example, but I'm afraid that next you're going to give some other requirements that don't directly apply to this one. In other words, the solution will depend on all the requirements for the task, but you've not explicitly described them.

Comment: No, nothing at all is wrong with textContent. THAT'S IT! Thank you so much. BTW I have a good excuse why I didn't know of that: I've been a long-time SELFHTML user and they do not tell any word about textContent. On Windows, this is not supported until IE 9, so it is kind of a newer "feature".

Comment: Using `.textContent` will also get the `Action!` text. What are the specific requirements you face for targeting text?

Comment: *"but ultimately why is that text not wrapped in an element?"* - Because I have to live with what the webmaster coded, as I'm trying to parse another guy's site, rearranging some minor things. (Think of an add-on I want to write myself to make life easier on a specific site :)) -- You're right, you will actually get ALL the plain text stuff in the specific block, which is not good. Seemingly it's not possible to group *each* of the texts by pushing them into an array, i. e. so that [0] gets assigned to "++This is the plain text" and [1] to Action!.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is what you need, because you didn't specify what you need to be an exact output in your example code.

If you need to literally [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)
you could use function like this:

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/7fFWn/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the text nodes within an element, I think you'll need to iterate over the element's childNodes and fetch the text nodes. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/jusak/2/edit) a quick-and-dirty example of a function that will fetch only the text nodes from a given element (it also skips any text nodes that are just whitespace, since those are often added as a result of HTML formatting but don't really mean anything to a human).

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Looks interesting. The `innerText`/`textContent` browser fork one-liner felt a bit hard to read for me at first though...took me quite a moment. But nevermind ;)